# PostgreSQL Can't do simple query after use copy function

Tags: postgresql

I'am using PostgreSQL and PHPPgAdmin. I have data in the file `ext.csv`, and I'm using the `COPY` function to import the data. I have already made a table with 15 columns and imported my `data.csv` to this table via function copy.

The problem is that I can't identify my column table with query. For example:

```
select customer_name from gis
```

produces the error:

> Query failed: ERROR: column "customer_name" does not exist LINE 1

Why this happen? I also checked in PHPPgAdmin and there the `gis` has a column and data.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a different `schema` from `public` in the database ?

Comment: Details? Are you setting `search_path`? What's the output of `\d gis` in the `psql` client? PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you capitalized the column name when creating it, eg "Customer_Name".

If so, you must `"double quote"` it where you refer to it elsewhere.

Comment: thanks so much craig ringer, i try to alter table the column, and now it's work. Best Regard.

Comment: @user2522265 So - was it a case sensitivity problem? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . In future, please show `\d` output from `psql` for the relevant tables - and include your **exact PostgreSQL version** in all questions.